# What's the difference when asked for "debit or credit" by a store when using credit and debit cards?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, debit-card

When purchasing something in a store with a credit card or a debit card, the cashier may ask "credit or debit"?

I was wondering what the point is using a credit card in a "debit" way? How is it compared to using a debit card directly?

What is the point  of using a debit card in a "credit" way? How is it compared to using a credit card directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are two different ways of processing payments. They go through different systems many times, and are treated differently by the banks, credit card issuers and the stores. Merchants pay different fees on transactions paid by debit cards and by credit cards.

- Debit transactions require PIN, and are deducted from your bank
  account directly. In order to achieve that, the transaction has to
  reach the bank in real time, otherwise it will be declined. This
  means, that the merchant has to have a line of communications open to
  the relevant processor, that in turn has to be able to connect to the
  bank and get the authorization - all that while on-line. The bank
  verifies the PIN, authorizes the transaction, and deducts the amount
  from your account, while you're still at the counter. Many times
  these transactions cannot be reversed, and the fraud protections and
  warranties are different from credit transactions.
- Credit transactions don't have to go to your card issuer at all. The
  merchant can accept credit payment without calling anyone, and
  without getting prior authorizations. Even if the merchant sends the
  transaction for authorization with its processor, if the processor
  cannot reach the issuing bank - they can still approve the
  transaction under certain conditions. This is, however, never true
  with debit cards (even if used as "credit"). They're not deducted
  from your bank account, but accumulated on your credit card account.
  They're posted there when the actual transaction reaches the card
  issuer, which may be many days (and even many months) after the
  transaction took place.
- Credit transactions can be reversed (in some
  cases very easily), and enjoy from a higher level of fraud
  protection. In some countries (and most, if not all, of the EU)
  fraudulent credit transactions are **never** the consumer's problem,
  always the bank's. Not so with debit transactions.

Banks may be encouraging you to use debit for several reasons:

1. They don't share the risk (see fraud protection differences)
2. They get to deduct the money right away, they may be paying the
   merchant later (depending on the contract between the merchant
   and the processor)

Merchants will probably prefer credit because:

1. They don't have to maintain communication to processor at all times
   (although now with the Internet connections, it is less of a problem
   than when they had to make a phone call on each card).
2. They can accept payments over the Internet and over the phone.

Consumers will probably be better off with credit because:

1. Its better protected against fraud
2. Easier to reverse transaction (dispute)
3. Allows deferring the actual payment (credit cards only)
4. Many credit cards offer rewards, very few debit cards do, and if they do - the rewards are much lower.

Comment: That's odd.  Regarding who's promoting credit/debit, I thought it was the other way around.  Our credit union told us to "Choose Credit" because then the merchant pays for the transaction.  The merchants like debit more for the opposite reason.

Comment: @mbhunter well, the merchant fees will probably be lower for debit cards, that's true. They will also not be having charge-backs. I was aiming at why the merchants would **not** want debit cards. It depends on the kind of merchant, some don't care at all.

Comment: I worry that the `Merchants will probably prefer credit`... bit is a guess at best, and likely wrong: credit companies often charge merchants up to 3% of every transaction, I image real money for them would trump the conveniences you list.

Comment: @Shep actually, fees for debit transactions are much higher when lower amounts are involved.

Comment: @littleadv I've been having a hard time finding hard numbers on this one. From what I understand there can be a baseline fee for both credit and debit transactions, and credit always charges a flat fraction of the transaction.

Comment: @Shep that depends on the merchant service provider, not always there's a flat fee. For debit transactions there's a flat fee, in the US its somewhere between $0.25 and $0.5, so depending on the amount - credit fee may be lower.

Comment: I agree that it depends a lot on the provider, but  based on the assumption of a 3% charge on credit transactions, and a 30 cent charge on debit transactions (none on credit), the threshold where debit becomes cheaper is 10 dollars, right?

Comment: @Shep and vast majority of credit card transactions is below $20...

Comment: After seeing this question bubble up, I noticed that it was not made clear that the reason the clerk asks the question with credit cards is that they can't tell if the card you present is a credit card or a debit card that can use the VISA or Mastercard network. Selecting "debit" with a credit card will likely fail the transaction.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your bank and your terms of service, but using the card one way or the other may affect things such as how long it takes to process, what buyer protections you have, etc.  It also affects the store as I believe they are charged differently for debit vs credit transactions.

Answer (score 2):

When using a debit card in a "credit" way, you don't need to enter your PIN, which protects you from skimmers and similar nastiness.

Also, assuming it's a Visa or Mastercard debit card, you now have access to all of the fraud protection and other things that you would get with a credit card.

The downside for the merchant is that credit card transaction fees are typically higher than debit card transaction fees.

I'm less familiar with using a credit card in a "debit" way, so don't have anything to offer on that part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add about using debit card as "credit" vs "debit" way: In addition to the difference of having to enter the PIN when using "debit" mode (vs having to sign in "credit" mode), for stores that offer cash back (i.e. get cash out of your account at the same time as paying), you can only get cash back when using "debit" mode.

Answer (score 0):

Credit in debit way - the card simply functions like a debit card for that transaction - pulling cash from your checking account. No difference.

You've simply discovered the fact that some banks are using the same piece of plastic for two functions, debit which draws funds directly from your checking, and credit which offers you time to pay a bill the comes in some time later. It's a personal choice.

Comment: Thanks! "Credit in debit way - the card simply functions like a debit card for that transaction - pulling cash from your checking account. No difference." Does it mean that a credit card can be used to withdraw money from an ATM and without interest generated from the day one of borrowing?

Comment: No, but if used as a debit card it can pull cash from your checking account.

Comment: But for a credit card, I do not have a checking account with the credit card company, although I set up to pay my credit card bill from another bank's checking account.

Comment: If it's not linked to a checking account, it can't be used as a debit card, i.e. there's no account to debit from.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised by all the pro-credit answers here, debit has some definite advantages.

Most importantly, when you pay with a credit card, the merchant pays around 3% of the transaction to the credit company. In many states, they are *forced* to charge you the same amount, and this is [frequently toted](http://www.dallasnews.com/investigations/watchdog/20130627-merchants-charging-extra-for-using-credit-or-debit-cards-face-more-than-a-warning-letter.ece) as ''consumer protection''. But consider what this means for the business: they loose money for every credit transaction, and they're legally forbidden to do anything about it. So you're taking 3% from a business and handing it over to a massive cooperation.

To make matters worse, the buisness is inevitably going to have to raise their prices (albiet by a small amount), so in the end the average consumer has gained nothing. On the other hand, the credit card company wins big, and they use their profits to pay lobbyists and lawyers to keep these rules in place. To put in the worst possible light, it's essentially legal extortion, verging on corruption.

As for the fraud protection offered, while it may be true that credit cards will offer a more hassle-free reimbursement (i.e. you just don't have to pay the bill) if your card is stolen, consumer protection laws also extend to debit: in many cases your bank is legally required to cut you a check for all the money you lost.

Comment: "Most importantly, when you pay with a credit card, the merchant pays around 3% of the transaction to the credit company"  As a customer, I really don't care.

Comment: *To put in the worst possible light, it's essentially legal extortion, verging on corruption* - and how then would you propose that the issuing banks and transaction networks get paid for the services they provide, if they're not able to collect interchange fees?

Comment: @dwizum: One alternative is that the merchant can pass the interchange fee along as a separate item on the receipt.

Comment: yeah this seems pretty obvious to me: if the business was allowed to charge customers for the credit transaction you could have an efficient system where the business charges what something costs and the credit company charges what it costs them.